# How do I create a RegExp to match 1 but no more than N consecutive words in a text file using sprintf?

Tags: regex, matlab, printf

Defining a word as a consecutive sequence containing any number of 
alphabetic  characters  or  apostrophes followed  by  0  or  more  blank  spaces. (0, because the very last word in the string will not be followed by a blank space).
This is the regEx I am using, but I cannot get it to work:

```
str = sprintf('[a-zA-Z_](0|\s){1,N}','text.txt');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't delimit words with "zero or more" spaces. There would be no way to know if a word ends or not unless a specific character separates them.

**EDIT**: The OP clarified in the comments that they want "one or more spaces" OR the literal character `0` to delimit words.

The following should work for 1 or more spaces. Note that double quotes are needed to denote a `'` character in a MATLAB string.

```
([''a-zA-Z_]+(0|\s+)){1,N}
```

- `[''a-zA-Z_]+` matches one or more characters considered to be part of words
- `0` matches the literal character 0
- `\s+` matches one or more whitespace characters
- `( ... )` considers the contents as a group
- `a|b` matches `a` or `b`
- `{1,N}` captures any number between 1 and N times

Comment: Spot on.  This is what I would have done too.  BTW, this was a homework question that someone wrote yesterday... what tipped me off was the `0 or more spaces` part of the problem... which absolutely makes no sense.  That could mean that `aaa` would be classified as three words.  I asked for clarification on that matter, but the OP deleted the question before they replied.

Comment: Nice explanation! Is it possible the single quotation mark at the beginning of the square bracket should be outside it/removed though (i.e. for use with `sprintf``)?

Comment: @Benoit_11 - Yes you are right.  The single quotation needs to be double quotations, or MATLAB will think you are trying to end a string.

Comment: @eigenchris - I believe the string to input into `regexp` should be: `'[''a-zA-Z_]+\s+){1,N}'`.

Comment: @Benoit_11 You are right. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: @rayryeng Thanks for the help. If it is homework, at least the OP made an attempt to solve the problem.

Comment: @eigenchris - Yup, definitely.  The other deleted question was a `give me teh coodz`, which I vehemently closed.  Also, my pleasure with the help!

Comment: @rayryeng - The `0 or more spaces` part of the code refers to having the digit `0` or a space after a word. (0, is what matlab would understand when reached the final word in the text, which is not followed by a white space).

Comment: @AlfonsoD. That makes more sense. You were on the right track with the`(0|\s)`, then.  You've probably figured things out now but I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: @AlfonsoD. - Yes, that makes more sense.  Your original problem statement is contradictory to this new statement.  I suggest you update your problem so that this is reflected.  The original wording is very confusing.